# PHP Zend GData Picasa/Photo Properties

Tags: php, zend-framework, properties, gdata, picasa

I do not know if it is a global Zend property storage system or what, but when I create the following kind of code:

```
$serviceName = Zend_Gdata_Photos::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($username, $pass, $serviceName);

// update the second argument to be CompanyName-ProductName-Version
$gp = new Zend_Gdata_Photos($client, "Google-DevelopersGuide-1.0");

$userFeed = $gp->getUserFeed("default");
foreach ($userFeed as $userEntry) {
    echo $userEntry->title->text . "<br />\n";
}
```

I cannot seem to get all of the attributes for the specified $userEntry.  When I do print_r, it just gives me the structure of the element, not the actual data.

**My question is** how do I get a list containing items such as "title" for $userEntry?

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it's not exactly an answer, but have you tried to debug using the lines below?

```
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
if ($e->getResponse() != null) {
    echo "Body: <br />\n" . $e->getResponse()->getBody() . 
         "<br />\n"; 
}
// In new versions of Zend Framework, you also have the option
// to print out the request that was made.  As the request
// includes Auth credentials, it's not advised to print out
// this data unless doing debugging
// echo "Request: <br />\n" . $e->getRequest() . "<br />\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n"; 
}
```

gl
Paulo Bueno.

Edit: See also this post [Zend_Gdata_Photos listing all albums and photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424762/zend-gdata-photos-listing-all-albums-and-photos).

Comment: Yes, I currently use that (I just wanted to get right to the point... ie. stand up, be brief, be seated).  Essentially that just catches "property {name} does not exist".  Thanks for the reply though!